# Excel VBA macro for one column, if true, apply formula to another column

Tags: vba, excel

For context:
[image: Untitled.tiff]
I would like for the program to look through column `B`, identify the first "`< / >`" (which is purely stylistic and can be changed if necessary - it's only used to break up the data) as the start of a week at cell `B9` and the next "`< / >`" (end of the week) at `B16`. So the range I'm interested in is `B10-B15`. It would then sum those numbers from `J10` to `J15` (Earned column) and paste that sum in `L16` (Week Total column). The same could then be done with 'Hours' and 'Week Hours'. For the following week (and thereafter) the 'end of the week' "`< / >`" becomes the start of the week, and the program continues until `B200`.

I don't have any experience with VBA and so made the following incomplete attempt (based on what I had found online) but felt too out of my depth not to ask for help.

```
Sub Work()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rngFound As Range

    Set rng = Range("B:B")

    Set rngFound = rng.Find("</>")

    If rngFound Is "</>" Then
        If Cell = "</>" Then

        End If

End Sub
```

Thank you for any help and please let me know if I can be clearer or elaborate on something.

Comment: You seem to be missing End If? I think Find returns a Range, not a String. So you should compare it with Nothing. (Not Nothing actually). When you find this information what do you intend to do with it?

Comment: FYI, I see you are a new user. It is good form on this site to vote up answers that help you and accept the answer that answers your question. Doing so will motivate others to continue to help you with future questions.

Comment: I would have but I need 15 reputation to do that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will loop through 200 lines, looking for your symbol. When found, it will sum the numbers in column J for rows between the current row and the last symbol.

I've included two lines that will update the formula. To me, the 2nd one is easier to understand.

```
Sub Work()
    Dim row As Integer
    row = 4
    Dim topRowToAdd As Integer 'Remember which row is the 
                               'top of the next sum
    topRowToAdd = 4

    While row <= 200
        If Cells(row, 2) = "</>" Then
            'Cells(row, 10).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[" & -(row - topRowToAdd) & "]C[0]:R[" & -1 & "]C[0])"
            Cells(row, 10).Value = "=SUM(J" & topRowToAdd & ":J" & row - 1 & ")"
            topRowToAdd = row + 1
        End If
        row = row + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I had in mind. I just changed the '10' to '12' in:

            Cells(row, 10).Value = "=SUM(J" & topRowToAdd & ":J" & row - 1 & ")"

to get the sum on another line. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Work()
    Dim rng As Range, rngFound As Range

    Set rng = Range("B:B")

    Set rngFound = rng.Find("</>")

    If rngFound.Value2 = "</>" Then
        'whatever you want to do    
    End If

End Sub
```

So at a second glance it looks like this. If you'd like to make it structured you'd need to use a *countifs* function first.

```
Sub Work()
    Dim rng As Range, rngFound(1) As Range

    Set rng = Range("B1:B200")
On Error GoTo Err 'it is quite possible it will run into an error if there are no matches and I'm too lazy for structured solution
    Set rngFound(0) = rng.Find(What:="</>", LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext) 'finds the first
    Set rngFound(1) = rng.Find(What:="</>", LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext, After:=rngFound(0)) 'finds the first after the first (i.e. the second)
    Set rngFound(0) = rngFound(0).Offset(1, 8) '8 is the difference between B and J, row shifts as per description, I advise you to make it a variable
    Set rngFound(1) = rngFound(1).Offset(-1, 8)
    If rngFound(1).Row > rngFound(0).Row Then 'if it's not higher, then it recurred and found the first range again
            rngFound(1).Offset(1, 2).Formula = "=SUM(" & Range(rngFound(0), rngFound(1)).Address & ")" 'L column will have the sum as a formula
        Else
            MsgBox "There is a single match in " & rng.Address(False, False)
    End If

If False Then
Err:
    MsgBox "There are no matches in " & rng.Address(False, False)
End If
End Sub
```

Now for the grand finale:

```
Sub Work()
    Dim rng As Range, rngFound() As Range, rngdiff(1) As Long, rngcount As Long

    Set rng = Range("B1:B200")
    rngcount = rng.Cells.Count
    ReDim rngFound(rngcount)
    rngdiff(0) = Range("J1").Column - rng.Column ' the range that needs to be summed is in column J
    rngdiff(1) = Range("L1").Column - rng.Column ' the range containing the formula is in column L

On Error GoTo Err 'it is quite possible it will run into an error if there are no matches and I'm too lazy for structured solution
    Set rngFound(0) = rng.Find(What:="</>", LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext) 'finds the first
    'loop starts
    For i = 1 To rngcount
        Set rngFound(i) = rng.Find(What:="</>", LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext, After:=rngFound(i - 1)) 'finds the next
        If rngFound(i).Row > rngFound(i - 1).Row Then 'if it's not higher, then it recurred and found the first range again
                rngFound(i).Offset(0, rngdiff(1)).Formula = "=SUM(" & Range(rngFound(i - 1).Offset(1, rngdiff(0)), rngFound(i).Offset(-1, rngdiff(0))).Address & ")" 'L column will have the sum as a formula
            Else
                Exit Sub 'if it recurred the deed is done
        End If
    Next i

If False Then
Err:
    MsgBox "There are no matches in " & rng.Address(False, False)
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Will create an overview at home.

Comment: If you are not able to answer properly then next time just wait till you are at home. Answers, typically, should have more content then just code. For all we know you are on vacation and it will take a couple of days for you to get home.

Comment: Your answer is a comment for OP to add an `End If` ;).

Comment: On one hand you are absolutely right @Matt, the form that was here was not particularly helpful. I needed time and it was a convenient place to keep a draft with a link to the forum. I hope its current structure makes up for the hiatus of its predecessor.

Comment: You will hate me, but I will return and make it loop tomorrow.

Comment: I might be a bit narcistic but I love this. Actually there's two more things I could add: structured error handling and saving array size by relaying between 0 and 1. Good thing I'm not in 1996 to deal with these.